# Calinski-Harabasz calculation slower in R clusterCrit than Python sklearn

Tags: python, r, performance, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I want to calculate the Calinski-Harabasz index for a large number of datasets. A quick test showed that [R's clusterCrit implementation in intCriteria](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clusterCrit/) is much slower than the [corresponding function from Python' sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.calinski_harabasz_score.html#sklearn.metrics.calinski_harabasz_score). Here is the test case (I can share the test.tsv if needed).

```
import numpy as np
import time
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import calinski_harabaz_score

d = np.loadtxt('test.tsv', delimiter='\t')
km = KMeans(n_clusters=2, max_iter=10000)
k = km.fit(d)
start = time.time()
ch = calinski_harabaz_score(d, k.labels_)
end = time.time()
print 'CH:',ch,'time:',(end - start)
```

Run it (using Python 2.7)

```
python CH.py
#CH: 482.766811373 time: 0.434059858322
```

Do the same in R

```
library(clusterCrit)

d <- as.matrix(read.table('test.tsv', sep='\t'))
k <- kmeans(d, 2, iter.max = 10000, nstart=10)
start <- Sys.time()
ch <- intCriteria(d, k$cluster, 'Calinski_Harabasz')
end <- Sys.time()
cat('CH:', ch[[1]], 'time:',end-start)
```

Run it in R (3.4.4)

```
source('CH.R')
# CH: 482.7726 time: 1.770816
```

I also tried using calinhara function from the [fpc package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fpc/index.html) but that's also quite slow.

Any way I can improve the speed of Calinski-Harabasz (and possibly other cluster validity indices) R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure R is often pretty slow because of the interpreter.

To see this, compare dbscan from the `fpc` and `dbscan` packages.

If you want an R module to be fast, rewrite the code in Fortran or C.

The same also largely applies to Python (although the Python interpreter appears to be slightly faster than R's). But in many cases the workhorse is `numpy` code which is low level optimized. And in other cases, sklearn includes `cython` modules, that is a subset of Python that can be compiled into C and then to native code.

Answer (score 1):

The `cluster.stats` function from the R package `fpc` uses a distance matrix to compute the CH and runs very fast. This is what I am using. Otherwise, you can take advantage of packages such as `Rfast` (the function `cova`) to compute the covariance matrix more quickly. Here's some modified code of the FPC calinhara that uses the original matrix:

```
calinhara_modified <- function(x,
                               clustering,
                               cov_x = NULL,
                               verbose = FALSE){
  require(Rfast)
  cn=length(unique(clustering))
  clusts <- sort(unique(clustering),decreasing = FALSE)
  if(is.null(cov_x)){
    if(verbose) message("No correlation matrix given. Computing one from scratch.")
    # https://rdrr.io/cran/Rfast/man/cova.html
    cov_x <- cova(x = x, large = TRUE)
  }
  x <- as.matrix(x)
  p <- ncol(x)
  n <- nrow(x)
  cln <- rep(0,cn)
  W <- matrix(0,p,p)
  for (i in 1:cn)
    cln[i] <- sum(clustering==clusts[i])
  if(verbose) pb = txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = cn, initial = 0, style = 3)
  for (i in 1:cn) {
    if(verbose) setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
    clx <- x[clustering==clusts[i],]
    cclx <- cova(x = as.matrix(clx), large = TRUE)
    if (cln[i] < 2) 
      cclx <- 0 
    W <- W + ((cln[i] - 1) * cclx)
  }
  if(verbose) close(pb)
  S <- (n - 1) * cov_x
  B <- S - W
  out <- (n-cn)*sum(diag(B))/((cn-1)*sum(diag(W)))
  out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the code in the version of [R optimized by Microsoft](https://mran.microsoft.com/rro)? I am pretty sure you will see an improvement.

Also, it seems that you are not taking into account the time that can be taken by compilation to intermediate language for python because your data are relatively small and you run your code only once. Does the comparison change when you run it multiple times?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I have not tried Microsoft's R (didn't know about it). I have tried running it multiple times resulting in similar speed.